# How to know event in kaplan Meier?

Tags: survival, kaplan-meier

Below is the Kaplan-Meier curve for  analysis of minutes from hospital admission to patient being setup in an ICU bed.

1. For this analysis, what’s the event? What’s the time origin?
2. Describe what the line on the Kaplan Meier Curve shows (what is on each axis, how can you read this to interpret it, etc.).
3. Based on the way you found the median survival time, explain under what circumstances the median survival time would be undefined.

[image: 1]

My proposed answers are;

1. Assuming that events are ICU admission, the date of admission to the hospital (with hours and minutes0 will be time origin.
2. X axis title should be "time to ICU dmission (minutes)", y axis title should be "No ICU admission". Each downword step represents admission to ICU (event happened).
3. As I obtained median survival time visually from the curve (~ 75 minutes), the median will be not reached (undefined) if it doesn't reach below 50% of the y axis.

My edited plot is as follows;

[image]

Please let me know if my thoughts are correct.
Appreciate your precious advice.

Comment: On your first solution, note that survival analysis is measuring "time to event". It requires a common starting point, not in terms of time but in terms of experience (this way you can compare people who arrive at different times). So, from your prompt, the time origin (ie. when you start counting time to event) is hospital admission, and the event you're measuring to is getting situated in an ICU bed.

Comment: @ToddBurus Thanks a lot. Any input on the other points will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to think through #2 more in light of the new info on #1.

Comment: @ToddBurus Thanks. i added my edited plot to my question. please let me know what you think

Comment: The vertical axis of a survival curve graph represents "Percent survival", which in your case is "Percent waiting for a bed".

Comment: @ToddBurus. Agree with your comment as it look much better than "No ICU admission'. Thanks a lot.